# Call Modal windows and return to original windows

Tags: ms-access, modalviewcontroller

I want to implement search UI by Modal form mode and it can be opened from different forms.  After Modal form is closed, Modal form will pass the select record ID back to calling form.

For exmaple, I will have customer seach Modal form.  It can be opened by Sales Order, Quotation, Invoice, or AR form (calling form) when user want to search customer name.  Once the searching is done, Modal form will pass the selected customer ID back to the calling form and calling form can use the selected customer to do tasks.

I tried to use getfocus on the calling form.  But, it does not work since get focus will not be trigged if calling form has object.

How can I get control and receive passed back ID from Modal form after Modal form is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the calling forms you declare a form object variable `WithEvents`. If your search is triggered you open your search form, set the variable to the opened form and wire up the close event.

In the `Close`-Event handler you can then process the value that is the result of the user interaction in the search form.

The search form should have the `PopUp`-Property set to True.

Code in the calling form:

```
' general declarations area 
Private WithEvents frmSearch As Form

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Const FORM_NAME As String = "frmSearch"

    DoCmd.OpenForm FORM_NAME, acNormal
    Set frmSearch = Forms(FORM_NAME)
    frmSearch.OnClose = "[Event Procedure]"

End Sub

Private Sub frmSearch_Close()
    ' process the result here, 
    ' assuming result is in control txtSearchResult
    MsgBox frmSearch.txtSearchResult.Value
End Sub
```

This solutions is based on the assumption that the user closes the search form, when he is done with the search. If that is not the case, you could define your own event in the search form and handle that instead.

Comment: Thank you. I never use WithEvnets. With your answer, I browse some other web sites, WithEvents is really a good feature.  Question: for the frmSearch.OnClose = "[Event Procedure]", should the "[Event Procedure]" be "[frmSearch_Close]"?

Comment: I figure it out. Copy all of your code into calling form without changing anything . It works perfrectly. Thank yo agian for your help.

Comment: The solution is perfectly to set subform form event from main form.  How to set event of subform control from main form and the event function is in main form module?